# Forcing a new page for first chapter only in article style under memoir class

Tags: sectioning, memoir, double-sided

I am using memoir class with article style as I want the short chapters to run continuously. I would like the first chapter alone to start on a recto page. `\newpage` does not force an extra blank left page which would solve the problem. Would be grateful if some LaTeX guru could help.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from another stackexchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\cleartorecto` should do the trick.

Comment: Brent Longborough,
Thanks a ton. It did do the trick:-)
Cheers,
Mohan

Comment: @Werner: Thanks for boistering my self-confidence :-)